# How to delete all lines except lines which have a colon in the 4th column in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have an extremely long text file with `data:data:data`, I'm trying to trim it down to only data with 3 characters before the first colon so it would be like `xxx:data:data` for every line while still keeping the data after the first colon.

From:

```
xxx:data:data
xxxxxx:data:data
xxxxx:data:data
xxx:data:data
```

To:

```
xxx:data:data
xxx:data:data
```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^:]{4,}.*\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
[^:]{4,}    # 4 or more any character that is not colon
.*          # 0 or more any character 
\R?         # any kind of llinebreak, optional
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you gotta mark all lines that contain a colon in the 4th column.

Press Ctrl-F, switch to the Mark tab, click Regular Expression and enter `\n...:` in the textbox. Make sure the `. matches newline` checkbox is NOT checked. Press the Mark button.

In the menu go to Search -> Bookmark -> Inverse bookmark.

In the menu go to Search -> Bookmark -> Remove bookmarked lines.